# ASSEMBLER - как можно организовать цикл

Tags: ассемблер, циклы

Здравствуйте! Помогите найти как можно больше вариантов организации циклов на ассемблере. 
 Вот, например, через

```
DO 3, END1
...
END1:

LOOP:
j.ne LOOP
```

Ещё можно через DOFOR..Я буду всем благодарен за ответы!

Comment: `loop label` не устроит? :)

Comment: Ну собственно можно использовать любые команды приводящие к передаче управления. т.е. все виды jmp, loop, при большом желании даже инструкции call, ret, int, iret. А вот все остальное что вы указали, типа каких то DO - это не инструкции процессора, а макросы вашего конкретного ассемблера и рассматривать их нет никакого смысла ибо они генерят код с использованием вышеназванных инструкций

Comment: @Mike Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.